# Not able to Group table on percentage Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

**Edit : Database - SQL server 2014**

I am trying to Calculate **Daily Percentage Of Student "Present"** like this :

[image]

But I Getting Result like this :

[image]

**Only while Calculating Percentage** I am not able to group Rows based on Class. 
With Out percentage Calculation , Result are grouping Fine

My Student Attendance table..

[image]

This is My Query...

```
SELECT CM.ClassName ,SB.SubjectName ,
count(sa.Day14) Total,
sum(case when sa.Day14 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) Present,
sum(case when sa.Day14 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Absent,
(SELECT CAST(
             CASE 
                  WHEN count(sa.Day14) = 0 
                     THEN 0 
                  ELSE (sum(case when Day14 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end)* 100)/(count(Day14))
             END AS nvarchar(100))) as [Present%],
AttendanceDate from studentattendance SA 
    inner join studentmaster SM on SA.StudentID = SM.ID  
    join ProfessorMaster p on SA.ProfessorID = p.Id 
    join Classmaster CM on SA.ClassID = CM.ID 
    inner join SubjectMaster SB on SA.SubjectID = SB.ID 
    where 
        sa.ProfessorID = '36' and sa.AttendanceDate = '2015-09' and SA.AdminId ='29'
    group by CM.ClassName, SB.SubjectName, SA.AttendanceDate,sa.Day14
```

What I am Missing ?

Comment: Please create sqlfiddle or add insert scripts in question for sample data

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
"If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." I.e remove the column sa.Day14 from GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that you are doing a count on Day14 group by Day14. With this you can't do sum in the same query as you specified a group by already. So you have to split your query.

Lets say your attendance table looks like this for a particular subject/class on a particular day.

```
         StudentID Day14    
        46                A
        47                P
        48                P
```

If you are using Oracle,then create a CTE. Else create a view to count 'A' and 'P'.

```
         select distinct(Day14), count(*) as AorP  from yourTable group by Day14
```

Now create another CTE/view to get the total sum and percent like below

```
     select DAY14, AORP*100/(select sum(AORP) as yourView from tbl2) as percentage from tbl2
```

This will give you result like

```
          Day14 PERCENTAGE        
          P           66.67
          A           33.33
```

Now join this view to your main query to get PERCENTAGE based for Present or Absent. You can also use this view as an inline query (like

```
 select col1,(select Day14 as AbsentPercent from newView where id=something and Day14='A')
```

Note: This view is just for example, You have to add at least 1 unique identifier to join to your main table later. To capture missing entries, use appropriate outer join.

Answer (score -1):

I got much Smaller Solution :) ...

Calculate Percentage in Datatable[Or any ResultSet in Code] ...

My Query (Not calculating Percentage )

```
SELECT CM.ClassName ,SB.SubjectName ,
count(sa.Day14) Total,
sum(case when sa.Day14 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) Present,
sum(case when sa.Day14 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) Absent,
'' [Present%] ,
AttendanceDate from studentattendance SA 
    inner join studentmaster SM on SA.StudentID = SM.ID  
    join ProfessorMaster p on SA.ProfessorID = p.Id 
    join Classmaster CM on SA.ClassID = CM.ID 
    inner join SubjectMaster SB on SA.SubjectID = SB.ID 
    where 
        sa.ProfessorID = '36' and sa.AttendanceDate = '2015-09' and SA.AdminId ='29'
    group by CM.ClassName, SB.SubjectName, SA.AttendanceDate,sa.Day14
```

and in DataTable ......

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                var Total = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(dr["Total"]));
                var Present = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(dr["Present"]));
                dr["Present%"] = (Present * 100) / Total;

            }
```